# Need a SQL query to get data from SQL Server database for a given period with certain condition

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have a SQL Server database with a table `dbo.sales` with 7 columns.

First column contains different sales person names, on column 2 to 6 other information, on column 7, sales average.

**Question**: what I need is a query to get all sales person details (all seven columns in Excel) if their sales average is more than 60% between a given date.

**For example:**  in my database, I have data from 01/05/2016 to 31/05/2016, if I enter a period in my Excel sheet between 25/05/2016 to 31/05/2016 and my required average for ex. 60% (should be changed as per my need), then I need all the sales person details who continuously have sales average of more than 60% between 25 to 31st May 2016.

If a sales man average was dropped below 60% on 28th May, then I don't want to see him on my report. In simple words, I need all sales person who continuously hitting 60% or more on average sales within my search period.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) with **their** code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the SQL code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. Also, update the tags to reflect the DB-Server you are using: MySQL **or** SQL-Server.

Comment: This is unlikely to be about MySQL. Please [edit] your question to remove that tag.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the sales period date is within the table, but if it is, that query should work for you:

```
;WITH PeriodSales as (
    SELECT * FROM Sales
    WHERE SalseDate between @StartDt and @EndDt)
SELECT * FROM PeriodSales
WHERE SalesPerson not in (
    SELECT SalesPerson FROM PeriodSales
    WHERE CASE WHEN IsNumeric(salesavg) = 1 
            THEN CAST(salesavg as Decimal) ELSE 0 END <= 60.
    );
```

Comment: Why you need a CTE? Seems just one query can do this.

Comment: You are right. I was just tired to type "SalseDate between @StartDt and @EndDt" twice. Even made a spelling mistake in "SalseDate". Less typing - less mistakes.

Comment: Many thanks Slava. I got the error " Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 45 to data type int." Please note that i can't change the database type. Can you please help to fix this by adjusting the query.

Comment: You did not specify that your SalesAverage is varchar. Please provide samples of that value. That will impact query.

Comment: Sorry Slava for not providing correct information. In my sales.dbo , I have 7 columns and all are data type varchar. Out of this, important 3 columns are salesmanname, date, salesavg. I want to see the salesmen who had continuous of more than 60% of salesavg in between my search dates.

Comment: Samples: "59"/"59.5"/"59.3%"/"0.595" - how salesavg is stored?

Comment: Hi Slava. Its like 45/45.11 / 45.12 /45.18/52/58........if decimal is there then rounded to 2 decimals, otherwise round figure like(55,65,75). Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've changed the last line. Try it now.

Comment: Hi Slava. I am getting message " Query timedout expired. I pasted below my query. Can you check and correct me where i went wrong.Qry = "WITH cte as (SELECT * FROM sales WHERE[Date1] between (' " & dfrom & " ')And  (' " & dto & " ' ))SELECT * FROM cte WHERE salesperson not in (SELECT salesperson FROM cte WHERE CASE WHEN IsNumeric(salesavg) = 1 THEN CAST(salesavg as Decimal) ELSE 0 END <= 60);"

Comment: That is performance problem. How many records in your table? Is [Date1] also Varchar? If not, is it Indexed? Run that query in SSMS and wait for the result. Do not forget to press Ctrl-M to get Query plan.

Comment: date1 is NOT Varchar but its not indexed. I want the report sort on salesperson.

Comment: That means query scans the whole table and if it reads it from a slow drive and if there is not enough memory and CPU resources, it might easily go beyond 30 seconds.